# HDFS block storage

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

- 1)I have a hdp cluster with 2 datanodes. But the replication factor
  for hdfs is 3. Where is the 3rd replica block stored in this case ?
- 2)If I upload a file in hdfs (with the replication factor as 3  ) ,
  shouldn't the file size increase by 3 times in hdfs (as there are 2
  extra copies)
- 3)Is there a way , that I could check which block of data
  resides in which datanode (I understand that metadata info will
  be in name node , but is there a command that provides me that info) 
  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Because the NameNode does not allow DataNodes to have multiple replicas of the same block, maximum number of replicas created is the total number of DataNodes at that time.

Reference: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html#Simple_Coherency_Model (Under Replica Placement: The First Baby Steps)

This means if you have 2 datanodes, your replication factor cannot be 3.

2) Your file size will be the same. However, using three number of replicas will increase your storage overhead. I mean what if your file is 2 GB. You are keeping your file using with 3 replicas. This means you are allocating 6 GB (2 GB is for your original file and 2+2 GBs are for copies) storage space for your file.